# Trying to build Electron app with VSTS fails saying "error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator."

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-devops, electron

Using VSTS to build an Electron app but I keep having issues with my NPM tasks:

I am not the dev, I'm devops trying to get this to build in VSTS running the npm install VSTS task and that seems fine, but then I run the npm Custom task where my command is `npm run electron-build` and then it fails.

I am running this as the root admin so I am not sure why that message is coming up.

ALSO: if I rdp into the VM that has the vsts agent on it and run the same NPM commands it builds its only when VSTS builds it that it fails.

here is the output I get from VSTS

```
50375 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\LGBUILDADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-c7d6f0879aedfd51.lock for E:\Agents\LG-04\_work\244\s\node_modules\.staging
50376 verbose stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'E:\Agents\LG-04\_work\244\s\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\dashdash\node_modules'
50377 verbose cwd E:\Agents\LG-04\_work\244\s
50378 verbose Windows_NT 6.3.9600
50379 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\LGBUILDADMIN\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
50380 verbose node v8.11.1
50381 verbose npm  v5.5.1
50382 error path E:\Agents\LG-04\_work\244\s\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\dashdash\node_modules
50383 error code EPERM
50384 error errno -4048
50385 error syscall scandir
50386 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'E:\Agents\LG-04\_work\244\s\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\dashdash\node_modules'
50386 error  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'E:\Agents\LG-04\_work\244\s\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\dashdash\node_modules'
50386 error   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir \'E:\\Agents\\LG-04\\_work\\244\\s\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\dashdash\\node_modules\'',
50386 error   errno: -4048,
50386 error   code: 'EPERM',
50386 error   syscall: 'scandir',
50386 error   path: 'E:\\Agents\\LG-04\\_work\\244\\s\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\dashdash\\node_modules' }
50387 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
50388 verbose exit [ -4048, true ]
Error: Npm failed with return code: 4294963248
```

---

Here is the package.json as well.

`{
    "name": "sds",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build --prod",
        "test": "ng test --sourceMap=false --watch",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "tslint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -e src/main.ts -e src/polyfills.ts -e src/test.ts -e e2e/src/*.ts",
        "format-all": "prettier --write **/*.{ts,js,css,scss,json}",
        "format": "pretty-quick --staged",
        "electron": "electron .",
        "electron-build": "ng build --prod --base-href ./ && electron .",
        "package-mac": "ng build --prod --base-href ./ && electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --prune=true --out=release-builds",
        "package-win": "ng build --prod --base-href ./ && electron-packager . sds --overwrite --asar=false --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"SDS\"",
        "package-linux": "ng build --prod --base-href ./ && electron-packager . sds --overwrite --asar=false --platform=linux --arch=x64 --prune=true --out=release-builds"
    },
    "private": true,
    "main": "main.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "6.0.0",
        "@angular/animations": "6.0.0",
        "@angular/common": "6.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "6.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "6.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "6.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "6.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "6.0.0",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.110",
        "angular-fastclick": "^1.0.4",
        "core-js": "^2.5.7",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "latest": "^0.2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.10",
        "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
        "shelljs": "^0.8.2",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.8",
        "@angular/cli": "6.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "6.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
        "@types/node": "^6.0.113",
        "codelyzer": "^4.4.2",
        "electron": "^1.8.7",
        "electron-packager": "^12.0.2",
        "husky": "^0.14.3",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~2.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
        "prettier": "^1.13.7",
        "pretty-quick": "^1.6.0",
        "protractor": "~5.1.2",
        "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
        "tslint": "~5.9.1",
        "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.13.0",
        "typescript": "2.7.2"
    }
}`

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Show us all the minimal configuration of your build pipeline.

Comment: You have an error message that's telling you the problem and a suggested solution. What have you tried to do to correct the error?

Comment: Can you show the detail logs by setting system.debug as true? And does it fail at npm install step, can you add the screen shot for how you config the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question was that I was using the wrong cli command and was building and then immediately running the app and that would cause a time out since the app was still running in the background. I changed to a command that would only build the app and that has worked ever since.

Comment: Since your problem has been solved, you can mark the answer by clicking √ symbol on the left of the answer. And it will also benefit other members who meet similar questions.